# Chrome Devtool Protocolを使ってChrome拡張のファイル選択画面を自動で操作する

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Devtool Protocolを使ってあるChrome拡張を自動で(人の手を介さず)操作したいです。

その拡張はデータをJSONで出力するもので、希望する出力先のディレクトリを選択して、許可を与える必要があります。
SeleniumというWebブラウザを自動で操作するライブラリを使用してChrome拡張の起動まではできたのですが、
ディレクトリの選択ができません。

どうやら、一般的な`<input type="file>`ではなくFile System Access APIというものを使用しており、
[File Upload](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/file_upload/)
上記リンク先の方法は使えませんでした。

そこで、より詳細にChromeを操作できる、「Chrome DevTool Protocol」を使おうと思ったのですが、そもそも、ディレクトリを選択する画面に介入してこちらが希望したディレクトリを渡すことはできるのでしょうか?

検索してみたところ、`Page.setInterceptFileChooserDialog`というイベントがあるのでできそうな感じなのですが、どのようにディレクトリを渡せばよいのですか?